# Shift + Numpad1 keys not working?

Tags: c++, mfc

//I want to change gear in my dash bord ,but there is no out but of these keys

```
 if(pMsg->wParam==VK_SHIFT && pMsg->wParam==VK_NUMPAD1) 
 {   
     m_name.SetVariable("gear","1");
 }
```

Comment: In your code, do you actually use wParam for both checks, or was this a typo?

Comment: The expression (pMsg->wParam==VK_SHIFT && pMsg->wParam==VK_NUMPAD1) is always false.

Answer (score 1):

The expression (pMsg->wParam==VK_SHIFT && pMsg->wParam==VK_NUMPAD1) is always false.

Try this instead:

```
 if ( (pMsg->wParam == VK_NUMPAD1) && (GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x80) != 0) ) 
 {   
     m_name.SetVariable("gear","1");
 }
```

You also may consider the use of an [accelerator table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg153544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: indeed wParam can only be one key. The proposed solution is the way to go.